# Flutter: How to insert a list to another using setAll(0,list)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to insert data at 0 index of `mPostList` everything I receive from the API on `Listview` Scroll.
This is my code,

```
List mPostList = List<PrivateChatMessageDataModel>();

var list = model.data.toList().reversed;
          mPostList.setAll(0,list);
```

But this code is clearning old data in `mPostList` and then inserting items in `mPostList`.
So my question is,

**How can I insert new data without losing previous data in list?**

---

I have checked the [official doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/setAll.html) to understand `setAll` method, code written there is as below,

```
List<String> list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
list.setAll(1, ['bee', 'sea']);
list.join(', '); // 'a, bee, sea'
```

As far as I understood it is removing data after 1th index. So is there is any other function to solve my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answering question myself*

I have solved this by `insertAll`,

```
  mPostList.insertAll(0,list);
```

**What does `insertAll` do?**

> This increases the length of the list by the length of iterable and shifts all later objects towards the end of the list.

Read more [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/insertAll.html)